# Trying to use one code for multiple database in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am trying to create a database for each restaurant in laravel 9.
basically when the admin add a new client. the code automatically create a new database for that client, then run migration for the new database, create users. when a user login we check which client it belongs to then login to the relevant database. basically one code for unlimited databases.
i wrote the code to dynamically connect to multiple databses in php, but never in laravel.

Error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection::getConnection()
> when trying to create a new database.

```
private function createDB($dbName)
{
    try {
        $outputLog = '';
        DB::getConnection()->statement("CREATE DATABASE :$dbName", array('schema' => "schema"));
        $this->migrate($outputLog);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $this->response($e->getMessage(), 'error', $outputLog);
    }
    return $this->response('Installation finished', 'success',$outputLog);
}

/// migrate database for new system
private function migrate($outputLog)
{
    try {
        Artisan::call('migrate', ["--force"=> true], $outputLog);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        return $this->response($e->getMessage(), 'error', $outputLog);
    }
    return $this->seed($outputLog);
}
// run seed folder after migration
private function seed($outputLog)
{
    try {
        // Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--force' => true], $outputLog);
        Artisan::call('db:seed', array_filter([
            '--class' => 'Database\\Seeders\\DatabaseSeeder',
            '--force' => true,
        ]));
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $this->response($e->getMessage(), 'error', $outputLog);
    }
    return $this->response('Installation finished', 'success', $outputLog);
}
```

Comment: " a database for each restaurant in laravel 9" - why not use the same database, but add the tenant selection properly? Having a distinct database per restaurant sounds like huge problems, for example when you want to migrate all of them to a new version

Comment: Not a great datamodel, it doesn't scale and is hard to maintain. To me, one restaurant would be just one record in the table with all restaurants. Every reservation, menu, or whatever that applies to this restaurant, would just use the id of this restaurant. You can now support millions of restaurants, in a single database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, creating new DB for each client is not good approach. In the future it will be very complex to maintain these DBs.
When it comes to you question, you can try this:

```
private function createDB($dbName)
{
    try {
        $outputLog = '';

        DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE $dbName");

        config(['database.connections.pgsql.database' => $dbName]);
        DB::reconnect('pgsql');

        $this->migrate($outputLog);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $this->response($e->getMessage(), 'error', $outputLog);
    }
    return $this->response('Installation finished', 'success', $outputLog);
}
```

Note: I assumed that you're using the 'pgsql' connection name, but you should adjust it if you're using a different name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. the reason I am creating a new database each time is that each restaurant needs to be independent of the other.

Comment: I have a follow-up question to the answer.  config(['database.connections.pgsql.database' => $dbName]);
        DB::reconnect('pgsql');
to
        $this->migrate($outputLog); after this should I not close the connection to this database? and reconnect to the master one?

Comment: yes, if you have code running after this function that expects the database connection to be pointing to the original "master" database, you should switch the connection back after completing the migration to the new database. After calling `$this->migrate($outputLog);` if you don't close the connection or switch it back, the connection will remain open to the new database. If you intend to always switch back to the original connection immediately after the migration, you can store the original database name, switch to the new one for migration, then switch back.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will implement it and update you.

Comment: Thank you very much.it worked but i had to remove the try and catch things.